# Using Squeeze Theorem for Riemann Integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, riemann-integration

Consider the function $f : [1, 3] → \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = 2x + 1, ∀x ∈ [1, 3]$. Use the Squeeze Theorem for Riemann integral to prove that $f ∈ \mathcal R[1, 3]$, the set of Riemann integrable functions on $[1,3]$.

I tried to look up examples for squeeze theorem but I can't find any. I understand the definition but I am lost on how to apply them.

Comment: What do you mean by $f\in[1,3]$? $f(2)\not\in[1,3]$. Did you mean the integral of $f$ is in $[1,3]$? Even then, $\int_1^3(2x+1)=10$...

Comment: sorry, it was a typo, it was supposed to be $f \in R[1,3]$

Comment: I'm still unsure of what you mean by $R[1,3]$. This is common notation for "real valued function on $[1,3]$", which your function clearly satisfies.

Comment: I think it meant that it is Riemann Integrable with [1,3]

Comment: How much have you learned about Riemann integration so far? Have you only seen Riemann sums?

Comment: Yes, that's all I know so far

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is an increasing function, given a partition $P=\{1=x_0<x_1<\ldots<x_n=3\}$, the lower and upper Riemann sums, $L(f,P)$ and $U(f,P)$, are easy to calculate:

\begin{align*}
 L(f,P) &= \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_{i-1})(x_i-x_{i-1}) \\
 &= \sum_{i=1}^n (2x_{i-1}+1)(x_i-x_{i-1}) \\
 &= 2\sum_{i=1}^nx_{i-1}(x_i-x_{i-1}) + \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_{i-1}) \\
 &= 2\sum_{i=1}^nx_{i-1}(x_i-x_{i-1}) + x_n - x_0 \\
 &= 2\sum_{i=1}^nx_{i-1}(x_i-x_{i-1}) + 2,
\end{align*}

and similarly

$$ U(f,P) = 2\sum_{i=1}^nx_i(x_i-x_{i-1}) + 2. $$

Since $x_{i-1} < \frac{x_{i-1}+x_i}2 < x_i$, one has $L(f,P) < I < U(f,P)$, where

$$ I:=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_{i-1}+x_i)(x_i-x_{i-1}) + 2 = \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i^2-x_{i-1}^2) + 2 = x_n^2 - x_0^2 + 2 = 10.$$

In fact, we can calculate $I - L(f,P)$ and $U(f,P) - I$ explicitly:

$$ I - L(f,P) = 2\sum_{i=1}^n\Big[\tfrac{x_{i-1}+x_i}2 - x_{i-1}\Big](x_i-x_{i-1}) = \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_{i-1})^2 $$

and similarly

$$ U(f,P) - I = \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_{i-1})^2. $$

Since $\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_{i-1})^2 \le \|P\|\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_{i-1}) = 2\|P\|$, where $\|P\|:=\max_{1\le i\le n}(x_i-x_{i-1})$ is the mesh of the partition, we have

$$I - 2\|P\| \le L(f,P) < I < U(f,P) \le I + 2\|P\|.$$

Letting $\|P\|\to0$ and applying the squeeze theorem, one sees that $f\in\mathcal R[1,3]$ with $\int_1^3f(x)dx = I = 10$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's show $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[1,3]$. To do this, we will write the integral as the limit of a Riemann sum and show it converges using the Squeeze Theorem. To construct the Riemann sum, first note that we are dealing with rectangles having width $$\Delta x=\frac{3-1}{n}=\frac{2}{n}. $$ Then the $x$ value of the $i^\text{th}$ rectangle is given by $$x_i=1+i\cdot\Delta x=1+\frac{2i}{n}.$$ We also need the value of $f(x_i)$, which is given by $$f(x_i)=2(x_i)+1=2\left(1+\frac{2i}{n}\right)+1=3+\frac{4i}{n}.$$
Putting this all together, we have (by definition of the definite Riemann integral),
$$
\int_1^3f(x)dx=\int_1^3(2x+1)dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\Delta x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(3+\frac{4i}{n}\right)\frac{2}{n}.
$$
It remains to use the Squeeze Theorem to show the limit
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(3+\frac{4i}{n}\right)\frac{2}{n}
$$
converges. To simplify things, note that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\left(3+\frac{4i}{n}\right)\frac{2}{n}=\frac{2}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n3+\frac{4}{n}\sum_{i=1}^ni\right)=\frac{2}{n}\left(3n+\frac{4}{n}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)=\frac{4}{n}+10.
$$
So we need to find two convergent sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ such that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n
$$
and
$$
a_n\leq \frac{4}{n}+10\leq b_n
$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. We can simply take
$$
a_n=\frac{3}{n}+10\quad\text{and}\quad b_n=\frac{5}{n}+10.
$$
Can you conclude from here using the Squeeze Theorem?

Comment: You have taken a sequence of partitions, but to show a function is Riemann integrable you need to consider *all* partitions. For instance, using your method one might incorrectly conclude that $\mathbf 1_{\mathbb Q}$ is Riemann integrable on $[1,3]$ with integral $2$, but we know this is not the case.